# redirectURL: for Phonegap iOS Facebook login on Node+Passport.js

Tags: ios, node.js, cordova, passport.js, deployd

Building an iOS app with **Phonegap** and **Passport.js** I point to

```
http://www.example.com/auth/facebook?redirectURL=...
```

to login. The server runs on `http://www.example.com`.

The `...` is my question! What do I fill there?

My files are served locally, something like `file:///var/...`

If I redirect to `window.location.href`, I get JSON output.

If I redirect to `http://www.example.com` it works, but then I'm simply browsing the online web-app, instead of the local files (and no Cordova-plugin-support anymore)..

Please advice!

Comment: use http://localhost/callback

Comment: `http://www.example.com/auth/facebook?redirectURL=localhost/callback` does not work (on Phonegap emulator)